# Setup Sharepoint site from one machine to another machine

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is there any fullproof and complete way to setup a sharepoint site from one machine to another machine with everything. Assume both machine have installed sharepoint server.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Backup of your site collection using backup command in power shell or using central Admin. Restore the backup using restore Command Power Shell.